# black screen ubuntu 18.04 with celeron J1900

Tags: boot, kernel, screen

I am having trouble with my celeron J1900 and ubuntu 18.04.
I cannot start preview or install it because it got direct stuck into black screen after the boot menu. The installer for ubuntu 16.04 works fine. However I have had this issue since any kernel newer than 4.6 would boot into a black screen direct after grub menu. So I guess it is a kernel issue with any newer kernels than 4.6 the graphic drivers is not working properly with the J1900 CPU built-in grpahics.

Is there other people out there having the same issue and knows any solution?